# if one three digit number (0 cannot be left digit) is chosen at random from all those that can be made from the set bellow.

Tags: probability

SET = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}

find the probability that the three digit number chosen is NOT a multiple of 5..

how would i do this question?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the number of digits and the fact that the left-most digit cannot be zero are irrelevant.  A number is a multiple of five if and only if it ends in five or zero, and there are seven possibilities for the last digit.  But this trick won't help determine the probability that it is not divisible by e.g. eleven.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. For a number to be a multiple of $5$ what properties should it satisfy?
2. Use $P(\text{Number is not a multiple of 5})=1-P(\text{Number is a multiple of 5})$

Comment: @ response ; a p(multiple of 5) = 6*7*2 = 84 right?

Comment: Somethings to think about: 1. Probability should be between $0$ and $1$, right? 2. Is repetition allowed?

Comment: @ response Well since the first digit can't be zero we only have 6 choices the second digit can be chosen from 7 numbers and the third for it to be a multiple of 5 can only be 0 or 5

Comment: Your calculation is correct only if repetitions are allowed. Are they? Also, per your first comment the probability of the number being a multiple of $5$ is $84$. That can't be correct as it is not between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @ response: I would assume that repititions are allowed. Am  i wrong?